# Sync audio - image production recording and avoiding the use of "Plural Eyes"

Tags: sync

In order to do this, I'm assuming it requires the clocks on the camera to be accurate, record keeping of time codes of the camera but a zoom does not have a time code so how do you match the two together.

Answer (score 2):

Clap your hands in front of the cameras and tab to transient to put it into the ballpark and then nudge it around until it either phase cancels or gets to where you want it.

It's pretty simple. If I'm given a speech at a podium to mix that is out of sync or someone shuffle-deleted on my dialogue track and it's way past the levels of undo to fix, I look for words that start with P or B and find the frame where the speaker's lip closes, put a marker, and then I put a sync point exactly where the P or B word starts in the audio, and then shift-cntrl-click and it's pretty close - then I nudge for perfection.

I've never used Plural Eyes but I just watched their promo video on the website and it actually looks like it would save a lot of time.

But isn't it more for video editors rather than audio?

Comment: Yeah its more of a video editor thing, I just have the project after it was already Plural Eyed and it is mushy and needs nourishment.

Comment: Ah - well, find a common sound and put sync points and sync them up relative to the video (hopefully there is at least one track synced with the video).

Comment: Even the guide tracks' a mess

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Wish I could be of more help.

Comment: Puraleyes has saved our production house endless hours of sync for picture editing. While it isn't perfect, for situations that you cannot get a clap for sync but have a guide track, it is a godsend. That being said, for proper production workflow, always try to have at least a clap and if you have the budget or working on a big job, then timecode jamming will make the post-house happy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing narrative filmmaking, use a clapboard slate and sync the frame where the slate closes with the sound of the slate closing.

If you are editing multiple sound files of the same event, find a percussive moment they have in common and use that as a reference. A hard consonant, the first snare drum hit of the song, etc.